# gridview select button to be a link to a page

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to have a gridview where the first field is a link to a page like mypage.aspx?selectedName=John if john row is selected or mypage.aspx?selectedName=Jim if Jim row is selected. How can I create the link for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TemplateField` to custom style a column.

```
<Columns>
  ... your other columns ...
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <a href='<%# "mypage.aspx?selectedName=" + Eval("Name") %>'>Click me</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Where `Name` is the name of the field that contains the name of the person.

Comment: is there any way I can encode the value Eval("Name") gives me?

Comment: Yes, by wrapping it into <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx">`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`</a>