# Calling a web page from a GridView select button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, asp.net-webpages

In an ASP.Net / VB.Net web page I would like to allow the user to Call another web page within my application passing some parameters to another page that uses these parameters as part of the DataSource "Select" statement from the "Select Button" of a GridView.

If this can be done, can you show the needed coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you need to call the web page do you want it as pop up? or you want to load the page?

ok here is it, the code tell me if it is working or not:
`<script type="text/javascript">
function basicPopup() 
{
    popupWindow = window.open("yourpage.aspx", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=600,left=100,top=30,resizable=No,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=No');
}
</script>`

on client click of button call this function  `OnClientClick="basicPopup();return false;"`

here is an answer i found in stackoverflow if you wish to open it as a page:
[gridview select button to be a link to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014920/gridview-select-button-to-be-a-link-to-a-page?rq=1)

Comment: We are doing a business solution for a private school and I'm working on the section that deals with keeping track of the parents of the students attending the school. The page with the select button contains a GridView that we want to allow the user to select a particular parent (the grid view just shows the mother and father names). When that button is clicked we would like to call a details page that allows the user to update the family in a DetailsView. We originally started this page by having the GridView and the DetailsView on the same page but we decided on separate pages.

Comment: If we call the page as a pop up can the user change the details?

Comment: yes he/she would be able to change. it will be just another page with same coding. that will appear as pop-up or use iframe set style and in src attribute give the path of page you want to display the coding will be same as you will do in any other page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you show the coding needed to call the page as a pop up? Thanks.